# Purpose of JavaScript function parameter

Tags: javascript, function

I can't understand the purpose of parameters in JavaScript functions. Let's say:

```
function sayWelcome(name) {
    document.write("Welcome to our page " + name);
}
```

What thing should do that name on first line? Why I should use that?

Comment: You should read some basic guide on functions...

Comment: I did, but I don't think that I get it.

Comment: _"What thing should do that name on first line?"_ you do whatever you want with it. Parameters tell the function to expect arguments to be passed to it on execution.

Comment: You could remove the function argument, and then try to `sayWelcome` to different people. *Edit:* And when you've done that, and present the code, I'll show you how easy things could get completely messed up with that approach, and why you should better use a function argument.

Comment: It serves the same purpose of other programming languages function parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you've got an automatic teller machine (atm). The atm wants to know who you are and what you want to return your money. So the atm function would look like

```
function atm(name, pin, money){
   if(all true){
      return money;
   }
}
```

And the user would do:

```
atm("john doe", 1234, 1000);
```